# How to run ffmpeg as systemd service?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, systemd

My problem is that when the system service starts `ffmpeg` at boot it creates defunct process. It just won't start. 
Even I try to start `ffmpeg` as subprocess by another app with systemd it also crashes.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with ffmpeg itselfs. It waits the input from stdin and somehow crashes when started by systemd, in console it starts as usual. 
To prevent it use `-nostdin` option for `ffmpeg`.
If you experiencing problems with audio devices try to make `systemctl --user` service so ffmpeg will start after user logon when all systems in proper state.